# Django handle photo upload

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have model whiuch has photo attachment.

```
class Forum_message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'forum_attachments')
```

I have my form(I prefer writing forms in pure html so I can have full access to modifying them)

```
<form action="/forum_new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="img_msg" type="file">
    <textarea name="new_msg"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

What do I write in my function 
`def forum_new(request):` in views.py to handle file upload and save new forum message to database?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the solution? There are plenty of resources which talk about how to handle form submission in Django.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this:

```
def forum_new(request):
    msg = Forum_message()
    msg.user = request.user
    if 'image' in request.FILES:
        msg.photo = request.FILES['image']

    msg.text = request.GET.get('text')
    msg.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

In **views.py**, you can use what is propose on the django website (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/)
If the picture is not so large, you can directly handle it as follow :

```
def forum_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = your_form_here(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/bar.html/')
    else:
        form = your_form_here()
    return render(request, 'url.html', {'form': form})
```

The file should be saved in your media files in the folder *forum_attachments*